# Setting condition

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to create a variable based on the below rule. My objective is to rank the items based on the serial variable if the day _start value (Mon_start, Tue_start, etc.) and the day _end standard deviation is less than 0.5. What is the best way to do this in R?

Rule:

```
=IF(AND(STDEV.S(D2,D4,D6,D8,D10, D12, D14)<0.5,STDEV.P(D3, D5, D7, D9, D11, D13, D15)<0.5),1,0)
```

Data structure:

[image]

Output:

[image]

Sample data::

```
df<-structure(list(serial = c(11011202, 11011202, 11011202, 11011202, 
11011202, 11011202, 11011202, 11011202, 11011202, 11011202, 11011202, 
11011202, 11011202, 11011202, 11011209, 11011209, 11011209, 11011209, 
11011209, 11011209, 11011209, 11011209, 11011209, 11011209, 11011209, 
11011209, 11011209, 11011209, 11011209, 11011209, 11011209, 11011209, 
11011209, 11011209, 11011209, 11011209, 11011209, 11011209, 11011209, 
11011209, 11011209, 11011209, 11011210, 11011210, 11011210, 11011210, 
11011210, 11011210, 11011210, 11011210, 11011210, 11011210, 11011210, 
11011210, 11011210, 11011210), start.end = c("Mon_start", "Mon_end", 
"Tue_start", "Tue_end", "Wed_start", "Wed_end", "Thur_start", 
"Thur_end", "Fri_start", "Fri_end", "Sat_start", "Sat_end", "Sun_start", 
"Sun_end", "Mon_start", "Mon_start", "Mon_end", "Mon_end", "Tue_start", 
"Tue_start", "Tue_end", "Tue_end", "Wed_start", "Wed_start", 
"Wed_end", "Wed_end", "Thur_start", "Thur_start", "Thur_end", 
"Thur_end", "Fri_start", "Fri_start", "Fri_end", "Fri_end", "Sat_start", 
"Sat_start", "Sat_end", "Sat_end", "Sun_start", "Sun_start", 
"Sun_end", "Sun_end", "Mon_start", "Mon_end", "Tue_start", "Tue_end", 
"Wed_start", "Wed_end", "Thur_start", "Thur_end", "Fri_start", 
"Fri_end", "Sat_start", "Sat_end", "Sun_start", "Sun_end"), time = structure(c(15300, 
13500, 15300, 13500, 15300, 13500, 15300, 13500, 15300, 13500, 
15300, 13500, 15300, 13500, 15300, 15300, 13500, 13500, 25200, 
15300, 53100, 13500, 25200, 25200, 53100, 54900, 25200, 25200, 
53100, 53100, 15300, 15300, 13500, 13500, 15300, 15300, 13500, 
13500, 25200, 26100, 53100, 53100, 28800, 56700, 28800, 56700, 
28800, 56700, 28800, 56700, 15300, 13500, 15300, 13500, 15300, 
13500), class = c("hms", "difftime"), units = "secs"), time1 = c(4.25, 
3.75, 4.25, 3.75, 4.25, 3.75, 4.25, 3.75, 4.25, 3.75, 4.25, 3.75, 
4.25, 3.75, 4.25, 4.25, 3.75, 3.75, 7, 4.25, 14.75, 3.75, 7, 
7, 14.75, 15.25, 7, 7, 14.75, 14.75, 4.25, 4.25, 3.75, 3.75, 
4.25, 4.25, 3.75, 3.75, 7, 7.25, 14.75, 14.75, 8, 15.75, 8, 15.75, 
8, 15.75, 8, 15.75, 4.25, 3.75, 4.25, 3.75, 4.25, 3.75)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -56L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(serial = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), start.end = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), time = structure(list(format = ""), class = c("collector_time", 
    "collector")), time1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), skip = 1L), class = "col_spec"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can separate the `start.end` column to 2 columns splitting on `'_'`. For each `serial1` and start or end value calculate standard deviation. If standard deviation of both start and end is less than 0.5 assign 1 to the new column or else 0.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  separate(start.end, c('Weekday', 'time'), sep = '_') %>%
  group_by(serial, time) %>%
  summarise(pattern = sd(time1)) %>%
  summarise(pattern = as.integer(all(pattern < 0.5)))

#    serial pattern
#     <dbl>   <int>
#1 11011202       1
#2 11011209       0
#3 11011210       0
```

If you want the same number of rows as the original data add `%>% left_join(df)` to the above answer.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `base R` methods with [`aggregate`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/aggregate)

1. `transform` the data by extracting the suffix part from 'start.end using `sub`
2. `aggregate` the 'time1', grouped by 'serial' and 'time' (created in 1) and apply the `sd`
3. `aggregate` again with grouping on `serial` and check `if` `all` the `sd` values are less than 0.5

```
aggregate(cbind(pattern = time1 < 0.5) ~ serial, 
     aggregate(time1 ~ serial + time, transform(df, 
    time = sub(".*_", "", start.end)), FUN = sd), all)
```

-output

```
    serial pattern
1 11011202    TRUE
2 11011209   FALSE
3 11011210   FALSE
```